# Iterate save in Node.JS across an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I couldn't use a simple for loop because request.save is a function. So I tried forEach. It works perfectly! Until I add in the request.save part and I get the following error message that breaks my app.

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
exports.submit = function (req, res) {


  Person.find({
      cellPhone: req.body.phone
  }).exec(function (err, people) {
      people.forEach(saveRequest);
  }

  function saveRequest(item, index) {

       var request = new Requests();
       request.start = req.body.start.value;
       request.finish = req.body.finish.value;
       request.phone = req.body.phone;
       request.offDay = req.body.date;

       request.user = people[index]._id;
       request.name = people[index].name;
       request.group = people[index].group;

       request.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
             console.log('request.save');
             return res.status(400);
           } else {
             // Remove sensitive data before login
             //user.password = undefined;
             //user.salt = undefined;
             console.log(request);
             res.json(request);
           }
       });
  }
});
```

Comment: you cannot call `res.json` multiple times, you should use res.write. As the save is asynchronous, I think the best is to use Promise

Comment: Thank you! What should the code look like? I tried res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); and I tried res.write(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); multiple times and they both broke the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you perform the *.save()* you pass an anonymous function that complete the response in case of error.

So you finish on the first save event error.

You should complete the response outside the save callback.

Maybe use events to sync your code, or better the generators.

Before your forEach loop:

```
let savedResponses = [];
let savedErrors = [];
...
```

Then your savedRequest:

```
function saveRequest(item, index) {

    var request = new Requests();
    request.start = req.body.start.value;
    request.finish = req.body.finish.value;
    request.phone = req.body.phone;
    request.offDay = req.body.date;

    request.user = people[index]._id;
    request.name = people[index].name;
    request.group = people[index].group;

    request.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('request.save error');
            savedErrors.push(err);
            // return res.status(400);
        } else {
            // Remove sensitive data before login
            //user.password = undefined;
            //user.salt = undefined;
            console.log(request);
            savedResponses.push(request);

        }
    });

}
```

Then after the forEach loop, you should wait the end of the asynchronous staff in the *.save()* callbacks.

You could use the *event* package or the generators or the promise pattern.

It depend on the version of your node.

When you have the code synched you could just complete your response checking for errors first:

```
if (savedErrors.length > 0) {
    res.status = 400;
    // ... report errors
}
```

Or just complete the response with the *savedResponses*.

Comment: I'm going to erase the response in my save function and add it directly after foreach

Comment: If you do that you have no guarantee that all the saves are performed as it's **asynchronous**. As I said in comment, you definitely should use Promises with `Promise.all`

Comment: @oliv37 I wrote it in my answer that the ascynchronous part should be handled in some way.

Comment: I would upvote this if I had 15 reputation. Thank you Mario

Comment: you cannot send the response after the forEach loop, the `savedErrors` and `savedResponses` will not be fully completed as the request.save is asynchrnous

Comment: @oliv37 Mario does mention that some asynchronous handling would be needed here but I think I agree it warrants more explanation. After request.save is called the program will continue on to the next statement. This is **not** the first line of req.save callback as you might expect, but the next line outside of that call. To make sure you wait on the data from request.save you can either wrap the responses in a callback that will handle them or add in promises (e.g. see the [Promise library I use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsvp))

Comment: @oliv37 I agree with your point, if you think feel free to edit my answer as you wish to include some example, or write your own answer to details your thoughts. My answer was focused on the OP case, that is not an asynchronous issue, but just to change the *res* object in a wrong moment. All other considerations are a plus.

Comment: as the OP accepts your answer I will not post mine, but I think using Promises for this kind of requirement would be better